# What is the meaning of the exclude tag in the resource tag of pom.xml?

Tags: maven

An employee who left the company wrote this in the pom.xml :

```
...
<build>
    <finalName>axian-oxalys</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
```

What are the consequences of the `exclude` tag in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag  on the resources part of the pom is used to exclude something that are on the resource path of the project and you don't want that inside the final jar. The wildcard /** means that you are excluding everything of the directory src/main/resources.

Comment: so if I place the `application.properties` file in the `src/main/resources` folder then I cannot get data the file ?

Comment: On the final jar, no. Check the target folder of your application. If there is something of your src/main/resources there, you will have to check on the pom if there is some configuration of the copy-resources plugin. Something like this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

When specifying a resource directory, every file within that directory may not be used. Thus, we may have to specify only the files that we want to include or specify the files that we want to exclude.

You can find more about exclusion here - [Maven reference documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: so if I place the `application.properties` file in the `src/main/resources` folder then I will get `NullPointerException` when writing `environment.getProperty("some.property");` ?